# IP in EventLogFile

Tags: eventlogfile

I want to know what is the different between CLIENT_IP and SOURCE_IP field in EventLogFile (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile.htm).

Comment: I can verify they diverge sometimes, not always.

Comment: I think that what we need is SOURCE_IP as this is the one of the end user's machine but what is the other one?

Comment: The client could be using a proxy and reporting a different IP because of that.

Comment: ok, but do you know the answer to my question?

Comment: If I knew I would have answered it. All I have is guesses, which is why I left comments. Figured sfdcfox would have answered this one already.